# pandas styling add attribute for cell/column

Tags: python, html, pandas, pandas-styles

I need to color specific columns in the table and convert it to html. I know it's possible to apply pandas styling to required subsets of data; for example, the next code snippet seems to work just fine. But the problem is that I need to set the same styling using `bgcolor` **html attribute**, not `CSS`. And I have found only [Styler.set_table_attributes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_attributes.html), which doesn't really help in my case. My current approach: I'm converting the html obtained from pandas to BeautifulSoup and adding attributes there, but it's not really convenient.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
st = df.style

def highlight(c):    
    color = 'green' if (c > 0) else 'red'
    return f'background-color:{color}'

st.applymap(highlight, subset=['C', 'D'])

with open('out.html','w') as f:
        f.write(str(st.to_html()))

# how i'm doing this now:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = BeautifulSoup(df.to_html(index=False), features='html.parser')

for header in ['C', 'D']:    
    index = df.columns.get_loc(header)
    
    for tr in res.table.tbody.select('tr'):
        td = tr.select('td')[index]
        c = float(td.text)
        td.attrs['bgcolor'] = 'green' if (c > 0) else 'red'

with open('out2.html','w') as f:
        f.write(str(res))
```

Comment: Got any solutions ?

Comment: Not really. Still using BeautifulSoup and manual iterations for this. Updated the description with the "solution" since it's not possible to add big code snippets in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `bgcolor` attribute using pandas styling by defining a custom function that returns the `bgcolor` attribute in an HTML style tag. You can then use this function with the `Styler.applymap()` method to apply the styling to the required subset of data.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
st = df.style

def highlight(c):
    color = 'green' if (c > 0) else 'red'
    return f'bgcolor: {color}'

st.applymap(highlight, subset=['C', 'D'])

with open('out.html','w') as f:
    f.write(st.to_html())
```

The `render()` method of the Styler object will return the styled DataFrame as an HTML string with the bgcolor attribute set using the style tag.

Comment: `render` was deprecated and no longer exists. Use `to_html`.